# Calculating overlap for svg elements

Tags: javascript, svg, scaling

Was looking for a highly optimized way to calculate which two elements out of hundreds of svg rectangles of varying height and width and random x y coordinates would overlap first when scaling down all of their coordinates at once, but not scaling down element sizes.    I know of comparing bounding boxes, but is there something more efficient.